# "Our program graduates" or "Our program's graduates" - which is correct?

Tags: saxon-genitive

I'm working with a friend on a short sentence for an announcement, and was asked whether the possessive should be used or dropped on *program:*

Current:

> Please congratulate our program's graduates.

We believe it may be more correct to simply use:

> Please congratulate our program graduates.

The graduates aren't owned by the program, so why express it as such? This seems like a common error.

Are we correct in this assessment?

**Edit:**

To expand on the question a bit, in the second case we are simply using *program* as an adjective for graduates: the *type* of graduate (ones of our program). I am aware that **'s**, the genitive case, can mean that something is *associated* with something else, and not strictly to convey ownership.

Thus, I know that the current form is correct, but am asking whether the second form seems improved, acceptable, or unusual in this example.

This may be a case of something similar to *orthographic incredulity*, where after staring at something too long it starts to appear wrong. That may be the case here, but I'd appreciate any constructive insight.

Comment: You are completely confused about the apostrophe-s clitic in English. It is ***NOT*** restricted to possession, and it is not an error. However, this is a duplicate question.

Comment: ... although there _is_ a move (endorsed by many) away from using the possessive 's in at least some non-ownership situations (eg Writers Guild, dogs home). Also, check here on attributive nouns vs possessives.

Comment: @tchrist I disagree that this is a duplicate. I am not asking whether *program,* an inanimate thing, can utilize apostrophe-s, I'm asking whether the usage of apostrophe-s is unnecessary, since the second version seems just as clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is an incorrect assessment.

Apostrophe-s is used as a vestigial remnant of the Anglo-Saxon genitive which has a number of distinct uses: as well as indicating *possession* it can be used in quite a standard way to indicate a *partitive* relationship, without implied possession.

Your second construction uses a "noun as adjective" construction. It is uncommon and awkward to use this construction when the genitive form is easily available (it is certainly a less productive construction than 's), in part because it provides fewer grammatical signposts for a reader. Using this construction with such ambiguous and multi-purpose words as "graduate" and "program" is inviting a reader to stumble.

The most common exception to this is in journalism, where the space restrictions due to print have carried over into other news media. If you are writing a headline with limited space the second form is probably an acceptable, -- if slightly gauche -- substitute for the first.

You seem to be an articulate speaker of English: don't let yourself lose your natural voice in a legalistic frenzy.

Answer (score -2):

While looking up information to answer this I found some guidelines [here](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/apostro.asp):

> Rule 10. Beware of false possessives, which often occur with nouns ending in s. Don't add apostrophes to noun-derived adjectives ending in s. Close analysis is the best guide.
>
> Incorrect: We enjoyed the New Orleans' cuisine.
>
> In the preceding sentence, the word the makes no sense unless New Orleans is being used as an adjective to describe cuisine. In English, nouns frequently become adjectives. **Adjectives rarely if ever take apostrophes.**

Even though "program" doesn't end with s, the fact that "adjectives rarely take apostrophes" makes it seem like the second announcement is "more correct."

Comment: This is not a case of a false possessive. "Program" doesn't already end in "s", which would make this true *if* it were only an adjective. In the first example I gave, it's a noun, so it is showing association to another noun, graduates. The second example, without apostrophe-s, uses *program* as an adjective, describing what type of graduate.

Comment: Yes, which is why I thought it fell in line with "We enjoyed the New Orleans cuisine," which is correct. Here "New Orleans" acts as an adjective.